# Fetching multiple random values for each values of one given field

Tags: mysql, random

I use **MySql** and I have a table like that:

> | id | category | field 1 | field 2 |

Values in the *category* field are not unique.

I would like to fetch 5 **random** rows for **each** category value

I can't find a solution in one query for that.

Could you help me on this one?

Thank you

EDIT:
I've found this:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  @lim := 5,
                @cg := -1
        ) vars,
        table_example t
WHERE   CASE WHEN @cg <> category THEN @r := @lim ELSE 1 END > 0
        AND (@r := @r - 1) >= 0
        AND (@cg := category) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
        category , id
```

But in this case, it fetches 5 rows for each category value (but it's ordered by id). I've tried to tweak that to order this randomly but I couldn't find anything satisfying...

Comment: I am thinking you'd need a procedure to do this. I do not believe a query can do that.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with MYSQL language, what do you mean by procedure ?

Comment: A stored procedure or a function that would get each category, get five records for each, and build a result table of everything. That's probably your best bet. What you want is very complicated for a single query.

Comment: Do you have some examples of such procedures by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this works, just a hunch:

```
SET @rownum=1;

SELECT t.id,CASE WHEN @rownum > 5 THEN @rownum:=0 ELSE @rownum=@rownum+1 
FROM table_example t WHERE @rownum<=5 GROUP BY t.category,t.id ORDER BY RAND()
```